# Checking that a player hasn't played a move already in RPS

Tags: solidity

For this line of code:

```
// check that the player hasnt played the move already 
require(choices[msg.sender] == 0);
```

As part of the below:

```
   // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
        
        pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
        
        /**
         * @title Storage
         * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
         */
        contract Game {
        
            uint8 constant ROCK = 0;
            uint8 constant PAPER = 1;
            uint8 constant SCISSORS = 2;
            address[] public players;
        
            // the public keyword will create a function with the same name as the mapping which will allow us to lookup the key outside the contract
            // no data is ever hidden in a smart contract deployed on a public chain and using `private` will not hide data in any way.
            mapping(address => uint8) public choices;
            
            
            function enroll() public payable {
                require(msg.value > .01 ether);
        
                players.push(msg.sender);
            }
        
            function play(uint8 choice) external {
                // check that the move is valid
                require(choice == ROCK || choice == PAPER || choice == SCISSORS);
                // check that the player hasnt played the move already
                require(choices[msg.sender] == 0);
                // set the choice for the players address
                choices[msg.sender] = choice;
            }
        
          function evaluate(address alice, address bob)
                public
                view
                returns (address add)
            {
                // if the choices are the same, the game is a draw, therefore returning 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 as the winner
                if (choices[alice] == choices[bob]) {
                    return address(0);
                }
        
                // paper beats rock bob/alice
                if (choices[alice] == ROCK && choices[bob] == PAPER) {
                    return bob;
                    // paper still beats rock (played in opposite alice/bob)
                } else if (choices[bob] == ROCK && choices[alice] == PAPER) {
                    return alice;
                } else if (choices[alice] == SCISSORS && choices[bob] == PAPER) {
                    return alice;
                } else if (choices[bob] == SCISSORS && choices[alice] == PAPER) {
                    return bob;
                } else if (choices[alice] == ROCK && choices[bob] == SCISSORS) {
                    return alice;
                } else if (choices[bob] == ROCK && choices[alice] == SCISSORS) {
                    return bob;
                }
        
            
            function pickWinner(address bob, address alice) public payable {
                if (evaluate(alice, bob) == bob) {
                    bob.transfer(address(this).balance);
                }
                if (evaluate(alice, bob) == alice) {
                    alice.transfer(address(this).balance);
                }
                players = new address[](0);
            }
            }        
        
                
                
            
           
        }
```

I don't understand why it checks that the player hasn't played a move already? It seems to me that the choice could be either 0, 1, or 2, for R, P, or S, so why is it that by requiring the mapping value to be 0, it is proof that it is a new move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array values are by default 0. So if you did not assign any value, they have to be 0.

Code of `ROCK` is also `0`. So require evaluation will be true if the user did not choose anything yet, or chose `ROCK`. Apparently, this is a bug, and you can fix this by changing the code of ROCK to something that is not `0`. Instead of [0, 1, 2] use [1, 2, 3], for example.

Comment: Ah I see! However, technically since you haven't set the value of the choices mapping at that point in time yet, it doesn't actually matter, right?

Comment: I didn't understand the question, sorry.

Comment: in other words, this line of code: 
 require(choices[msg.sender] == 0); 
actually comes before this line: 
  choices[msg.sender] = choice;
so, even if the player chose 0, that won't get added to the choices mapping until the end of the function, so setting the require statement to be equal to 0 initially is actually okay